# java.sql.SQLException: Unknown initial character set index '255' received from server for connector 8.0.11

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

While establishing the connection to a MySQL database, I'm getting the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown initial character set index '255' received from 
server. Initial client character set can be forced via the 'characterEncoding' 
property.
```

Upon googling, I got to know that we need to modify 2 params in my.ini or my.cnf.

I am using MySQL version 8.0.11 and it does not have this file.

Hence I modified these parameters using the SQL commands:
Please note name and duration are column name in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE courses MODIFY name VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;    
ALTER TABLE courses MODIFY duration VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE courses MODIFY name VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE courses MODIFY duration VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Hence my table looks like this

[image: Table]

After this, I restarted MySQL server, but I'm still getting the above error.

Please note I'm deploying my application in tomcat and running rest API call which will connect to the database. While connecting to the database, I'm getting the above error.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Connector/J 8.0.11. What does `connection.getMetaData().getDriverVersion()` return?

Comment: Note that changing the character set of a specific column will not change things for the connection character set. Exactly which two parameters did you find that you needed to change in your MySQL config? And have you tried specifying the `characterEncoding` connection property as suggested in the error message?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using MySQLWorkbench interface:

First click in your connection ->

[image]

After click in Options File

[image]

And change character-set-server and collation-server values to the values below:

[image]

Make sure to restart mysql server by opening services and restarting mysql server.

Comment: Not Worked for me

Comment: Options File showing  "Location of MySQL configuration file (ie: my.cnf) not specified" ?

Answer (score 14):

With version 8 the default characterset changed. When you add your character set to the connection URL like ?characterEncoding=latin1 it might work.

Comment: Added `?characterEncoding=utf8` in URL.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `?characterEncoding=latin1"` after your url String like this
for e.g.:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourDB?characterEncoding=latin1";
```

It might work.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need to download the latest connector j jar:

http://chillyfacts.com/java-sql-sqlexception-unknown-initial-character-set-index-224-received-server/

Comment: Hello i am using latest version of connector j jar only i.e i am using version of 8.0.11

Answer (score 4):

it is because of mysql-connector version , i,e. My-sql install version and dependency version did not match.

use same version for myS

Answer (score 2):

Use the same version of MySQL as well as mysql-connector.
If you are using tomcat then keep the connector in the lib folder of tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Just download latest version of hibernate jar file from
https://www.javatpoint.com/src/hb/hibernatejar.zip
and the MySQL connector jar file from
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Add connector dependency jar file in the POM file after a cross-check with your MySql server version  8.0.x add this dependency it was working for me mysqlmysql-connector-java     8.0.11

Answer (score 0):

I am using `springboot`,`liquibase`, `mysql`

I got solution:
This error occur just because of mysql connector in dependency and mysql server you install not match(in my case i am using lower version mysql connector and latest mysql server). So just change scope of mysql connector to `runtime`:

**maven**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**gradle**

```
dependencies {
//... other dependencies
runtimeOnly group:'mysql', name:'mysql-connector-java'
}
```

Or if problem yet not solve then use same version or nearby version for both mysql server and mysql connector.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your connection string should work:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourDB?characterEncoding=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the CharacterEnconding, useUnicode options will work

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true"

Answer (score 0):

Compatible version of mysql-connector-java should be required as per installed MySQL Server
---> For my installed  MySQL Server 8.0 I download   mysql-connector-java-8.0.20 in SoapUi/bin/ext folder or build path of project in eclipse.
it works for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Version 5.1.44 of mysql-connector-java.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.44</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it :
Add *characterEncoding=utf8* to the end of jdbc connection string

E.g. `connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/photo_app?" +  "user=root&password=root&characterEncoding=utf8");`

Answer (score 0):

use the newest version of mysql-connector

```
mysql mysql-connector-java 8.0.25
```